# django-autocomplete-light how to copy multi select fields

Tags: django-autocomplete-light

I'm using django-autocomplete-light with django 1.8.
I want to be able to copy the selected contents from one autocomplete field into another which requires overriding javascript code.

I tried duplicating the html content inside the autocomplete tool into another one in the browser debugger which looked good but when I click the save button in the admin page, it ignores my copied value.
Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps the form fields have the same name ?

Comment: That's a good point. I tried again making sure the field names are incremented and this time it worked; the main problem is that there are 2 spans. The second one is identical to the first except that it is hidden but when you click on it, you set the focus which makes the second span visible which I though is redundant and deleted it...long story short, I need  to copy both spans and make the second one hidden.

Comment: That really looks like a github issue that was investigated not so long ago, https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/757 I tried a crystal ball answer :D

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use an empty form for #form_template as such:

```
<div class = 'table' id="form_template" style="display:none">
    {{ formset.empty_form }}
</div>
<div class = 'table'>
                <table>
<!-- don't use #form_template in your actual form -->
```

From [github issue](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/757#issuecomment-254338360)

Comment: I'm not sure where this snippet should go. Is this for making a custom form? thanks

Comment: Dunno man, you haven't posted any code yourself, so I can't tell, sorry ^^